# the list stuck after clicking the save button

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a list attached to workflow , when adding a new item and click save, the form is stuck

before the list item saved and the form stuck after the workflow attached.

the workflow designed using sharepoint designer, it have one step "Wait for" action for test.

Has anyone faced this behavior before?

thanks